# Flutter keyboardType:TextInputType.number not working with TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter TextFeild While using keyboardType:TextInputType.number along with controller of type TextEditingController, unable to enter digits using number keyboard directly. First I have to press any special symbol such as '.','-' , and then type the numbers.

```
final expenseAmount = TextEditingController();
TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Amount",
          ),
          controller: expenseAmount,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        ),
```

[Screen Shots 1st unable to type number 2nd after . able to type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63LnG.jpg)

Comment: Which version of Flutter are you using?

Comment: the latest one 2.2.3

Comment: same issue here! have anyone tried to make an issue to the repository? @ManrajSingh

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I used `TextInputType.phone`. After executing these lines of code `controller.text = ''`, the numeric keypad became unavailable. `controller.clean` this helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issues, and to solve this Make sure you are not reinitializing the controller inappropriately, such as in the build method of your widget.

Answer (score -1):

change this line

```
final expenseAmount = TextEditingController();
```

to

```
TextEditingController expenseAmount = TextEditingController();
```

i think this will fix your problem.

Comment: does not work. What is not working is setting controller and `keyboardType: TextInputType.number,`. the controller does not emit values when on listen

Answer (score -1):

[image: See My screen]
You should try this

```
final TextEditingController price = new TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
   controller: price,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'Amount',
      hintText: 'MRP',
     ),
     textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
   ),
```

Other Solution:
you add the package: `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

```
    TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                    RegExp(r'[0-9]'),
                  ),
                ],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Price',
                  hintText: '0.00',
                ),
              ),
```

Refer `FilteringTextInputFormatter` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html)

Comment: Exit your app and and run **flutter clean** then run **flutter pub get** and run your App and see my screen

Comment: I tried the same in a different file and its working but not in this don't know what the problem is

Comment: uninstalled the app from the emulator then also didn't work out and used an actual device as well but the same problem persisted

Comment: Can you tell me the warning or error on console when you put/type value in amount textfield

Comment: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15351): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15351): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15351): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

Comment: these are from the debug console after i click on the textfield to type

Comment: I tried the above-given solution. But still facing same issue

Comment: @sunilkumar please check my updated answer(Other Solution) hope its help to you.

Comment: @ManrajSingh  Same issue i am facing .have you found any solution ?

Comment: @SachinSuthar I just created a new project with same code and that solved the issue.

Comment: @ManrajSingh Happy to help you

Comment: This doesn't explain why we can't get input values in `TextEditingController` when we set `keyboardType: TextInputType.number,`